# Why does git branch history remain when the branch has been deleted

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have deleted a branch in git, and have confirmed it no longer exists by running:

```
git branch -a
```

However, I am still able to view the branch, although unlabelled, using my Git GUI tool.

[image: branch]

Is this standard behaviour? I was expecting the history of that branch to be a part of the branch it was merged into.

Comment: Because those commits are still *reachable* from another reference (branch or tag), they and the ancestry path between them remains visible in your GUI.

Comment: @Jubos - how do I determine the route by which it is still reachable?

Comment: For branches, `git branch --contains <commit>`, where `<commit>` is one of the commit in the branch you deleted, will list the branches from which `<commit>` is reachable. Similar command for tags: `git tag --contains <commit>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The history of that branch *is* part of the branch it was merged into. If you run `git log` from the branch you merged into you'll see the commit(s) in the branch you merged from. They are part of the history.

So why are you still "seeing the branch"? Because what you see there is a series of ancestor-descendant relationships, not branches.

A "branch" in git is not a series of commits. We treat it that way, because it makes sense for our mental models, but a branch is just a movable tag. It's a name assigned to a specific commit. When you're working on branch X, and create a new commit, git creates that commit, sets its parent as the current commit that X points to, then moves branch X to point to the new commit.

So, suppose you're in branch master. Branch master is currently pointint to  commit 1 (I'll use numbers to refer to commits; git uses hashes, but it makes no difference). You make some changes, run `git commit`. What that means is that git creates a new commit, commit 2. Commit 2's parent is commit 1. Then moves the tag master to commit 2. So if you open your git GUI tool, you'll see that master is at commit 2, then a line to commit 1 below it. That's because 1 is 2's parent commit.

So now suppose you create a new branch. You run `git branch new; git checkout new`. Now you're standing in branch new. Branch new was created from you were standing, so it's also pointint to commit 2. In your GUI tool you'll see master and new are both pointing to commit 2.

Now make some changes, run `git commit`. This creates commit 3, which has commit 2 as its parent, and move branch tag new to 3. Branch tag master is still pointing to 2.

Now go back to master, `git checkout master`, then make some changes, `git commit`. Again, new commit (let's say 4), this one also has 2 as its parent. In the GUI tool you can see that both 3 and 4 have a line connecting them to 2.

Now, the part that's relevant to your question. Still in master, run `git merge new`. That will merge in branch new. So what is a merge in git? A merge is just a commit that instead of having one parent commit, has two parent commits. When you run `git merge new` what git does is create a new commit 5, and set *both commits 3 and 4* as its parents (4 because it's the one master points to, 3 because it's the one new points to). So if you open your GUI tool, you will see exactly what you would expect to see in this case: master pointing to 5, and *two* lines from it, one to 4, and one to 3, because *both* commits are 5's parents. Since you haven't told git otherwise, you still see the new branch marking commit 3.

Now, all this git history you created is completely independent of branches, and will still exist if you delete the branches. Remember, a branch is only  a tag attached to a commit. Deleting the branch doesn't delete the commit, or any of its history, it just removes the tag. So now you can run `git branch -d new`, and branch new will disappear. However, commit 3, which was "in branch new", will still be there. Commit 3's parent is still 2, and commit 3 is still one of 5's parents. So what happens if you look at the GUI tool? Well, you'll see commit 5 marked as master, then two lines coming out of it, marking commits 4 and 3 as its parents, then lines from 4 and 3 marking 2 as their parent, then a line from 2 to 1. So exactly the same as before removing the new branch.

I hope this makes it clear.